# Windows UMDF CComPtr IWDFMemory does not get freed

Tags: memory-leaks, com, driver, msdn, umdf

In my `UMDF` driver i have a `IWDFMemory` packed inside a `CComPtr`

```
CComPtr<IWDFMemory> memory;
```

The documentation of `CComPtr` says, If a `CComPtr` object gets out of scope, it gets automagically freed. That means this code should not create any memory leaks:

```
void main()
{
    CComPtr<IWDFDriver> driver = /*driver*/;
    /* 
      driver initialisation
    */

    {
        // new scope starts here

        CComPtr<IWDFMemory> memory = NULL;

        driver->CreateWdfMemory(0x1000000, NULL, NULL, &memory);
        // At this point 16MB memory have been allocated.
        // I can verify this by the task manager.

        // scope ends here
    }

    // If I understand right the memory I allocated in previous scope should already
    // be freed at this point. But in the task manager I still can see the 16 MB
    // memory used by the process.
}
```

Also if I manually assign `NULL` to `memory` or call `memory.Release()` before scope end the memory does not get freed. I am wondering what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558905(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If NULL is specified in the pParentObject parameter, the driver object
>   becomes the default parent object for the newly created memory object.
>   If a UMDF driver creates a memory object that the driver uses with a
>   specific device object, request object, or other framework object, the
>   driver should set the memory object's parent object appropriately.
>   When the parent object is deleted, the memory object and its buffer
>   are deleted.

Since you do indeed pass NULL, the memory won't be released until the `CComPtr<IWDFDriver>` object is released.

Comment: So what is good practice for this example? I want the memory the be freed at the end of the scope. What shall I chose as parent object, if not the driver itself?

Comment: I'm not familiar with UMDF, but I looked at how `IWDFDriver::CreateWDFMemory` is used, and in the places that specify a non-null owner, the typical owner is an `IWDFIoRequest` object.